# Inserting Query Each Single Query Results as Contents to a Combo Box

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, combobox

I have this query where I am expecting a lot of results.

```
private void addContentInCmbPhy() {
            DbClassesDataContext myDb = new DbClassesDataContext(dbPath);
            var match = from phy in myDb.Physicians
                                        select phy.Phy_FName;

            for(IQueryable<string> phy in match){
                cmbPhysicians.Items.Add(phy);
            }
        }
```

In my query above it will return several results, and I want those name results to be inserted as Items in my comboBox, how would I add it? it gives me this following errors

```
 Error  7   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement  C:\Users\John\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PatientAdministration\PatientAdministration\Pat_Demog.cs    415 43  PatientAdministration

Error   8   ; expected  C:\Users\John\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PatientAdministration\PatientAdministration\Pat_Demog.cs    415 40  PatientAdministration
Error   9   ; expected  C:\Users\John\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PatientAdministration\PatientAdministration\Pat_Demog.cs    415 43  PatientAdministration
```

Comment: My guess is that you are not showing the code which has there errors. I can't see any missing semicolons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you using the wrong looping statement?  It should be foreach instead of for.  If you are using a for loop then you need to have an incrementer.

Comment: I didn't see it! oh thank you for pointing that out. I got used to java syntax. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It is god if you have you `datacontext` inside of a `using` statement. Becuase then you just have the connection as long as you need. And you are disposing it directly after. I would probably do it something like this:

```
private void addContentInCmbPhy() 
{
    List<string> match;
    using (var  myDb = new DbClassesDataContext(dbPath))
    {
        match = (from phy in myDb.Physicians
                select phy.Phy_FName).ToList();
    }


    foreach(var phy in match){
        cmbPhysicians.Items.Add(phy);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the connection to the database should not be open more as it needs. And if you are using it in a using statement then you are disposing it properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void addContentInCmbPhy() 
{
    List<string> match;
    using (var  myDb = new DbClassesDataContext(dbPath))
{
   cmbPhysicians.Items.AddRange((from phy in myDb.Physicians
            select phy.Phy_FName).ToArray());
}

//  foreach(var phy in match){
//      cmbPhysicians.Items.Add(phy);
//  }
}
```